# Are image and link description text indexed by search engines or SE's built-in search functionality?

Tags: support, search, search-engine, search-indexing

In some of my questions in Arqade (e.g. [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/112568/4797)), I would put a screenshot to indicate what I'm talking about.

I was wondering if I should write the text in the screenshot in the question's body to get it indexed by search engines. Or will putting the text as an image description or link description also get them indexed by search engines (both external and SE's built-in search functionality)?

```
![Are text put here indexed by search engines?][1]  

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCXb6.png "What about here?"
```

[image: "Are comments like this indexed by search engines?"]

Comment: I would assume that the standard search engine rules apply. The thing you put in `[]` becomes the `title` attribute and the thing you put in `""` becomes the `alt` attribute.

Comment: And these standard rules imply what answer?

Comment: From my experiments, it seems Stack Exchange search doesn't search in image alt text, sadly.